# Swift: UITableViewCell "jumps" when expanding and a part is out of view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an UITableView with custom cells. Cells can be expanded when tapped.
I calculate the height with the delegate `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

The animation coming with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)` looks really nice but doesn't work if a part of the bigger expanded cell is out of the screen. Then it just kind of pops (it looks like a jump), no nice "sliding"- animation (sorry i don't know the right animation-phrases), like when the cell is completely visible on the screen.

I already tried out `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)` that made that nice sliding even if the expanded cell is out of the screen border but the upper part of my cell is just getting brighter for a moment and that doesn't look very fancy..

So anyone having trouble with that "animation" .None, too? ^^"

My did-select-func:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? ProviderNewTableViewCell {

            if expandedCells.contains(indexPath) {
                expandedCells.removeObject(indexPath)
            }
            else {
                expandedCells.append(indexPath)
            }

            //This prevents the last cell glitching into the decreasing cell above

            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({ () -> Void in
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
            })
            CATransaction.commit()
  }
}
```

My cell-for-row-func (the important parts ;) )

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProviderNewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProviderNewTableViewCell
     if expandedCells.contains(indexPath) {
        indexPathDetailViewDict[indexPath] = ProviderCellBuilder.sharedInstance.buildDetailView(cell, prov: current)
     }
}
```

Comment: Try implementing `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: No :/ cell still jumps when expanding and out of screen..